# Comma in Indexing

Tags: c#, excel, interop, excel-interop

I'm currently learning on how to write data to Excel sheets using C# and Interop and stumbled across some weird Syntax:

```cs
xlWorksheet.Cells[1, 1] = "ID";
```

It's obvious that this selects the A1 Cell but is this a shortening for `Cell[1][1]` or is the comma here some kind of Indexing operator like `^` or `..`? And if yes, to what evaluates it?

I haven't found anything about this online and I'm curious as I've nver seen this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here the `1,1` just means the A1 cell, or first cell in column A, no relation with arrays.

To create an indexer, you can use in a class like `public return_type this[int x,int y, int z] => ...`

Comment: Yeah I saw that but with the `[ ]` syntax it looks like some kind of Indexer, how can one implement an Indexer that takes arguments then? (If this the case what I think it is)

Comment: The cells are referred like arrays in C#, and the comma is like to refer in multi-dimensional arrays in C#

Comment: @Zer0 On any class you can define indexers in any way you like. For example: `public int this[int x, int y] => 0;` creates an indexer that no matter what `x` and `y` values you enter always returns `0`